# nginx user_agent redirect

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I want to redirect IE users to a static file, regardless of what page they were trying to reach.

My code is inside a server block:

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* msie ) { rewrite ^.+$ /msie.html last; }
```

No matter what I try, I either get a 404 or a 500 Internal Server Error. Am I doing this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do it by doing:

```
try_files $uri /msie.html;
```

Answer (score 2):

Above answer doesn't work any more for IE11 because string "MSIE" isn't available any more in user agent string.

Sample IE11:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

Sample IE9:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
```